# nginx serve multi index files from location

Tags: nginx

I want to archive that serving variable html file through different uri, below is my config.

```
server {
  listen 8888;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    root html/test
    index foo.html
  }

  location /another {
    root html/test
    index bar.html
  }
}
```

I want request for `localhost:8888/another` then response `bar.html` which present in my **test** directory, but I'm failed :(

how could I fix above config, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filename is constructed from the value of the `root` directive and the URI. So in this case:

```
location /another {
    root html/test;
    index bar.html;
}
```

The URI `/another/bar.html` will be located at `html/test/another/bar.html`.

If you want the value of the `location` directive to be deleted from the URI first, use the `alias` directive.

```
location /another {
    alias html/test;
    index bar.html;
}
```

The URI `/another/bar.html` will be located at `html/test/bar.html`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.